# Angular2 expression evaluation inside a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to code a generic component(in this case to sort an array) that doesn't know in advance the type of the elements to sort.
It could be the element directly if it's a string, a parameter if it's an object, a parameter of a parameter etc..

To do that I would need to provide the expression upon which to sort from the parent component.

For example in the component:

```
array.sort((a: any, b: any): number => {
        return a.[this.orderBy] > b.[this.orderBy] ? 1 : -1;
      });
```

Where orderBy is an Input like this: 'name' or 'object.name'

Basically I would like to do the same kind of expression evaluation that is possible in the HTML template ({{'..'}}) but in a Typescript method.

Is it possible?

Comment: template some variable inside the template then make the data available

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you suggesting a copy of the array containing only the elements filtered by the expression? Unfortunately I cannot do that I have to sort the array directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below,

```
sort(){
    let orderBy = "var1.var2";
    // orderBy = "name";
    let someArray = [{name: 'c', var1 : { var2 : 0}},{name: 'b', var1 : { var2 : 1 }}] 
    let result = someArray.sort((a: any, b: any): number => {
        return this.resolve(a,orderBy) > this.resolve(b,orderBy) ? 1 : -1;
      });
    console.log(result);
  }

resolve(obj, path){
    path = path.split('.');
    var current = obj;
    while(path.length) {
        if(typeof current !== 'object') return undefined;
        current = current[path.shift()];
    }
    return current;
  }
```

The only gotcha in above is your objects property name should not contain a `dot(.)`, like `{ 'first.name' : 'c', var1 : { var2 : 0}}`, Also you have to consider edge cases what if path is not present, else you should be good.

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cf2JRpmPowWxsx6eD774?p=preview).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Awesome! It works! I didn't know about shift, thanks for the tip !

Comment: Glad i could help, Cheers!!